# CSS lower down/cut an edge

Tags: css, reactjs, styles

I'm trying to make a row like this.

[image]

Code for so far what I tried,
JSX ->

```
<div className={styles.other}>
    <div className={styles.edgeCut}>
      <span className={styles.blueText}>Other Less-Common Paths</span>
      <span>
        I’m <strong>security concerned</strong><img className={styles.bottomImage} src="/arrow-right.svg"></img>
      </span>
      <span>
        I’m an <strong>investor</strong><img className={styles.bottomImage} src="/arrow-right.svg"></img>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS ->

```
.other {
  margin: 5vw 15vw;
  position: relative;
}

.edgeCut {
  padding: 1.5em 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(273.05deg, #b9ffee 11.12%, #c2f8ff 73.8%);
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 36px;
  transform: rotate(-0.38deg);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.blueText{
    color: #5C9FCF;
}

.bottomImage{
    height: 1em;
    width: 2em;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

It displays->

[image]

It doesn't cut the edges like the first image. How can I achieve this.
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `clip-path` for this sort of effect:

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

```css
main {
  align-items: center;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100v;
}

div {
  background: white;
  clip-path: polygon(0 25%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use clip path but clip path some times doesn't work in some browers.You can use background-linear property to get cutouts at edges.
Use this:

```
.other {
    margin: 5vw 15vw;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .edgeCut {
    padding: 1.5em 2em;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg,transparent 18px,#b9ffee  0)top left,linear-gradient(45deg,transparent 18px,#b9ffee  0)bottom  left,linear-gradient(-135deg,transparent 18px,#b9ffee  0)top right,linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent 18px,#b9ffee  0)bottom right;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-0.38deg);
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  
  .blueText{
      color: #5C9FCF;
  }
  
  .bottomImage{
      height: 1em;
      width: 2em;
      margin-left: 0.5em;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
```

it will display
[image]
and if you want to change the degisn
you can just change the background-size
like if you will do background-size:70% 30%;

you will get this:
[image]

you can also get circular edges if you want in circular you have to use different property.

Comment: Did you get your answer or you want another thing

Comment: `clip-path` is supported by 96% of browsers

Comment: Tried late.. used clip path, got desired output. Did try yours one too, it's an interesting option.. Will need to try out more to understand better